# Pseudo class is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'am newbie in html. Why is the code not working when I put any tag between "style" and "p" tags?

```css
p:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>example</h1>
<!-- problem is here -->

<p>Hello venus</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

Comment: There is no element `p` which is the first child of any element. First child is `h1` here.

Comment: you already pointed the problem in your code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `first-of-type`.

```css
p:first-of-type{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1>example</h1> <!-- problem is here -->

<p>Hello venus</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

`First-child` is just the first child, not first of paragraphs.

```css
:first-child {color:red;}

div h1:first-child {color: green;}
div p:first-child {color: blue} /* match nothing */
```

```html
<h1>example</h1> <!-- problem is here -->

<p>Hello venus</p>
<p>hello world</p>

<div>
  <h1>example</h1> <!-- problem is here -->
  <p>Hello venus</p>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use `:first-of-type` selector

```css
p:first-of-type{
    color:red;
 }
```

```html
<h1>example</h1> <!-- problem is here -->

<p>Hello venus</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`p:first-child` is targeting first child of body. You may need `p:first-of-type`

```css
p:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>example</h1>
<!-- problem is here -->

<p>Hello venus</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```